# Can the phrasal verb 'result in' be followed by a gerund?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can the phrasal verb 'result in' be followed by a gerund?
Example:

- We regret that this set of factors resulted in electing Trump, but it is time to move on.
- The accused expresses his regret that the hardship of his poor life resulted in breaching the law.

Or an alternative:

- The accused expresses his regret that the hardship of his poor life
  resulted in a breach of the law.

Does it go with an article or without in the last sentence (a breach of smth)? I would be grateful to hear if any of these is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: The gerunds are doing their job just fine. If 'a breach,' keep the article. It means the hardship was vast but the breach, *a* singular incident.

Comment: BTW, _result in_ isn't a phrasal verb; it's just a verb governing a specific transitivizing preposition, like _look at_ or _listen to_. Real phrasal verbs undergo particle shift, and are stressed on the particle, like _look the word up_.

Comment: What an excellent question. Your question is very interesting indeed. We would expect a gerund-participle clause to be able to occur as the complement of "in"  - without a subject so long as the subject of the G-P was the same as the subject of the main clause. But - to my grammatical ear at least - we can't. Hmmm. Nice data.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, but  why can the gerund-participle clause appear without an expressed subject here, even if it is notionally the same as the subject of the matrix clause? Bit weird isn't it?

Comment: Gerunds appear with indefinite subjects all the time. _[`Indef`'s] Playing the tuba at midnight is not a form of entertainment._

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I know :-) But what I don't understand is why they *can't here*.

Comment: I don't see (or hear) anything odd about subjectless gerunds with _result in_  -- _His actions resulted in destroying the settlement_. The subject of _destroying_ could be either _he_ or `Indef`, depending on context.

Comment: @JohnLawler It might be a pond thing, or it might be my idiolect, but that example sounds not quite right to me. I'll ask my fellow East-pondians tomorrow ...

Comment: @JohnLawler (Btw, I often don't know you've responded until months later 'cuz we don't get pinged if you don't '@' you comments to their recipients!)

Comment: @John Lawler - why are you (sort of) limiting the subject of the participle phrase to [indef]?  Can't it be definite (just like 'him')?